# How to implement a gravatar-like algorithm?

Tags: image-processing

For fun, I would like to implement something that takes an arbitrary string as input and returns a random image that is seeded from the string. It doesn't have to be super robust or anything. I'd love to be able to make something like the unicorn/pony gravatars that SO had a while ago.

If Gravatar were open source and had a plugin architecture for implementing new image types, I'd like to build one. But I wasn't able to find that.

I would like to use Python or Java if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look at the code that Stack Overflow itself uses for the unicorns: https://web.archive.org/web/20110224234102/http://unicornify.appspot.com/

Comment: only 11 years on and that link is now HTTP 500. :P

Comment: Updated link to archived version.